# how to post and response to post

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, post

I have asp.net button, I want when click to post to the following link 
https://www.cashu.com/cgi-bin/pcashu.cgi

with something parameters like the below form do

```
<form action="https://www.cashu.com/cgi-bin/pcashu.cgi" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="XYZ">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="66a31cd699d8d9cb454df1f6cec30c2c">
<input type="hidden" name="display_text" value="Baseball Hat">
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="CSH">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="125">
<input type="hidden" name="language" value="en">
<input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="asdasd-234-asdasd">
<input type="hidden" name="txt1" value="item27">
<input type="submit" value="Pay with cashU!">
</form>
```

I want to do that programatically and catach the return response , and write it on text

any idea how to do that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post

Comment: ok , this is the post, the post will redirect me on another site , when the user click button in it will  return to my page, how to response the returned request

Comment: You don't have to redirect the user. You make a http post on server side and directly show response to user.

Comment: the  http post will redirect me ,